# How to tell rsync to fetch files (fails with "No such file or directory")

Tags: linux, centos, rsync, wordpress, hosting-services

```
sudo rsync -avP ~/wordpress/ /var/www/html/
```

Error receiving is:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/root/wordpress" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 20 bytes  received 12 bytes  64.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1179) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Please help i am actually trying to connect centos with wordpress and i am receiving this error.
Thank you.

Comment: Help Rakhi pillai. Which bit of `change_dir "/root/wordpress" failed: No such file or directory` is unclear? That would help me understand how best to answer your question

Comment: Can yo explain what you're trying to do and why you're executing that command (i.e. which guide are you following).

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is trying to copy the 'wordpress' directory from their home directory, but sudo + tilde expansion is changing it to root's home directory. Replacing `~/wordpress/` with `/home/username/wordpress` should fix that.

Comment: Expansion of `~` is done by the shell before sudo is executed, so that's not a likely explanation.

Comment: Is this intentionally a copy between places on the same system? Or is it intended to be a remote copy?

Comment: Using rsync to copy files within a single host is overkill. And copying files either with cp or rsync is not a good way to maintain a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved. thank you.
The correct syntax was:

```
sudo rsync -avP /wordpress/ /var/www/html/
```